# Join and minify third party javascript libraries

Tags: javascript, angularjs, bundling-and-minification

I am developing a big project using AngularJs, and I am using a big quantity of externals libraries.

I have minified and joined my own javascript files yet, but I am not sure how can I join and minify all the external libraries without breaking my application. Any idea? Should I do that?

Thanks.

Comment: How do you join and minify your internal files?

Comment: Most of popular libraries already have minified version. For instance: http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js

Comment: I am using ASP .NET MVC for this project, and it has a feature for minifaying and joining javascript files. http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification

Comment: @ArtyomNeustroev I know that, but the files are too many, and I would like to join in one or two files. When I try to do that I have some collisions between the files, and the application doesn't still working. I would like to know what usually do other people in this situacion.

Comment: Maybe I shouldn't try to join them.

Comment: @jvrdelafuente Don't give up because you're getting collisions. That's simply a different problem that you need to solve. What errors appear?

Comment: @MikeRobinson I am not giving up, but I am not sure if It is a good practice to minify and join the external javascrits. I will add more details about the erros later. Thanks.

Comment: Joining external libs can be a good practice. You'll reduce the number of HTTP requests, improving page load time. If you have a -lot- of external libs, it might benefit you to look into requireJS, although you'll see less gain with it using Angular than with a traditional site. We have a similar scenario with our UI, and I've combined most our our third party tools into a libs.js file using grunt-concat and grunt-uglify.

Answer (score 0):

There are several methods to do this:

1. You can write own server on node.js + special libraries to do that
2. [Use grunt.js](http://gruntjs.com/sample-gruntfile)
3. [Google tool](https://developers.google.com/closure/?hl=ru)
4. [Brunch tool](http://brunch.io/)